# append 3 lists in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to know how to append three lists with Prolog.
It should work like this:

```
?- append([1,2],[2,4],[4,8],X).
X = [1,2,2,4,4,8].                % expected answer
```

I've tried a lot, but did not find a good solution for this.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: Append the first and the second, then the third to the result, maybe? BTW, can you show some of what you have tried? Maybe someone can spot the mistake in your code.

Comment: Please provide more information, show your code snippet, show your errors.

Answer (score 1):

library(lists) has [append](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2)/2 that works, provided you change your code this way:

```
?- append([[1,2],[2,4],[4,8]],X).
```

Comment: But how do I code this function myself ?
How does it work exactly?

Comment: @Human The link provided actually has a link to the source code. You didn't even bother to click on it.

Comment: If i click on it, it only shows me that:

append(+ListOfLists, ?List)
Concatenate a list of lists. Is true if ListOfLists is a list of lists, and List is the concatenation of these lists.
ListOfLists must be a list of possibly partial lists

Comment: the source is reachable clicking the [rightmost link](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#append/2)